Is it acceptable programming practice to reference a part of a slot (#[[1]], #[[2]], and #[[3]], for example)? If not, what alternative should I use?
Suppose I have a list of lists -- specifically, a rectangular array/matrix called myList:
myList = {
   {"a", 1, 10.1},
   {"b", 2, 20.2},
   {"c", 3, 30.3},
   {"d", 4, 40.4}};

Now suppose I wish to:

concatenate the first element of each sublist to itself,
square the second element of each sublist, and
cube the third element of each sublist.

I can think of two main ways to do this with a functional programming approach using Map:

map a named function across the list
map a pure function (also known as a pure anonymous function because it has no name).

Here is an implementation:
(* FIRST METHOD: map a named function across the list *)
myFun[arg_List] := {arg[[1]] <> arg[[1]], arg[[2]]^2, arg[[3]]^3};
firstMethod = Map[myFun, myList]

(* SECOND METHOD: map a pure function across the list *)
secondMethod = Map[{#[[1]] <> #[[1]], #[[2]]^2, #[[3]]^3} &, myList]

(* COMPARE METHODS BY OUTPUT *)
firstMethod == secondMethod

which gives this output:
(* {{aa, 1, 1030.3}, {bb, 4, 8242.41}, {cc, 9, 27818.1}, {dd, 16, 65939.3}} *)
(* {{aa, 1, 1030.3}, {bb, 4, 8242.41}, {cc, 9, 27818.1}, {dd, 16, 65939.3}} *)
(* True *)

My question is, in terms of programming best practices, is it acceptable to call #[[1]], #[[2]], and #[[3]] as I did in the second method? Or do you think this is conceptually awkward and/or computationally inefficient?
I know that it is possible to have multiple slots (#1, #2, ... or named slots, such as #name) in a pure function to denote multiple arguments. Instead of using a pure function with a single argument (#), should I somehow use a pure function with three slots (#1, #2, and #3)?
Addendum: testing the computational performance of the first and second methods
As an addendum, I can use AbsoluteTiming to compare the first and second methods in the case that myList is a very long list:
numAlphabets = 10^6;
myCharList = Flatten @ ConstantArray[CharacterRange["A", "Z"], numAlphabets];
myLongList = Transpose[{
    myCharList,
    Range[numAlphabets * 26],
    Range[numAlphabets * 26] + 0.1}];
Length @ myLongList

(* FIRST METHOD *)
firstMethod = Map[myFun, myLongList]; // AbsoluteTiming

(* SECOND METHOD *)
secondMethod = Map[
    {#[[1]] <> #[[1]], #[[2]]^2, #[[3]]^3} &,
    myLongList]; // AbsoluteTiming

(* COMPARISON *)
firstMethod == secondMethod

which gives this output:
(* {70.4882, Null} (* 70.4882 is the wall clock time in seconds *) *)
(* {64.8951, Null} (* 64.8951 is the wall clock time in seconds *) *)
(* True *)

So, the first and second methods are relatively close in terms of efficiency, with the second method being about 8% faster.

Clarity that leads to ease of program maintenance is often valued over minor speed improvements. So maybe myFun2[{label_, index_, value_}] := {label <> label, index^2, value^3}; — give names to the arguments that are self-documenting. (The ones I made up are nonsense like the sample data muList.) —— There's also the form myFun3 = Function[{label, index, value}, {label <> label, index^2, value^3}]; myFun3 @@@ myList

I meant to point out that myFun3 in my comment corresponds to {#1 <> #1, #2^2, #3^3} & @@@ myList. You asked about "should" and I already said named arguments can be helpful. That said, if myList is a large packed array, then performance may have a higher value.  For instance, if myList is packed, f @@@ myList cause myList to first be converted to an unpacked form, which takes extra time. -- BTW, myFun2 /@ myLongList takes 19+ sec. vs. 38+ sec. for the secondMethod. OTOH, {#1 <> #1, #2^2, #3^3} & @@@ myLongList takes 18+ sec. vs. 24+ sec. for myFun3 @@@ myLongList.

I find this quite readable. MapAt[f, myList, {All, 1}] // MapAt[g, #, {All, 2}] & //   MapAt[h, #, {All, 3}] &. Paraphrasing: Apply f to the entries in the  first column followed by g to the second column entries and then h to the ones in the third column. You are not limited to columns though and therein lies the flexibility that usually comes at the price of efficiency.

From looking at my WL code and the WL code written by people around me, I would say yes it is acceptable programming practice to refer to the Part of a Slot.  Whether you use parts of slots and Map, like
{#[[1]] <> #[[1]], #[[2]]^2, #[[3]]^3}& /@ mylist

or numbered slots with MapApply, like
{#1 <> #1, #2^2, #3^3} & @@@ mylist

is often just a matter of preference, or habit from whichever method you learned first.

This may be outside the scope of the question, but pattern matching using ReplaceAll or Replace seems to be faster than Map approach in this case. See the thirdMethod and fourthMathod (suggested by @RomaLee in the comment) below:
$Version
(* "14.1.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 16, 2024)" *)

numAlphabets = 10^6;
myCharList = 
  Flatten@ConstantArray[CharacterRange["A", "Z"], numAlphabets];
myLongList = 
  Transpose[{myCharList, Range[numAlphabets * 26], 
    Range[numAlphabets * 26] + 0.1}];

(* FIRST METHOD *)
firstMethod = Map[myFun, myLongList]; // AbsoluteTiming

(* SECOND METHOD *)
secondMethod = 
   Map[{#[[1]] <> #[[1]], #[[2]]^2, #[[3]]^3} &, 
    myLongList]; // AbsoluteTiming

(* THIRD METHOD *)
thirdMethod = myLongList /.
    {a_String, b_, c_} :> {a <> a, b^2, c^3}; // AbsoluteTiming

(* FOURTH METHOD *)
fourthMethod = Replace[myLongList,
    {a_String, b_, c_} :> {a <> a, b^2, c^3}, {1}]; // AbsoluteTiming

(* {32.7502, Null} *)
(* {32.623, Null} *)
(* {16.6671, Null} *)
(* {15.9004, Null} *)

firstMethod == secondMethod == thirdMethod == fourthMethod
(* True *)


It is absolute acceptable, but in your specific cases you you may use MapApply (@@@) as follows {#1 <> #1, #2^2, #3^3} & @@@ myLongList. It is 2 to 3 times faster than your second method. Your third method is somewhat error-prone, you should better use Replace[myLongList, {a_String, b_, c_} :> {a <> a, b^2, c^3}, {1}]

@RomaLee Thank you. You are absolutely right.  My third method has a weakness in the sense that the pattern can match with an unexpected part of the expression. I edited my answer and included your code as a fourth method. The second method is not mine ---  just copied from OP's Addendum :-)

@Kato Sorry, I was going to comment the original question but missed :).

You can use Inner and Construct.
With myList in OP and the list of functions
funcs = {# <> # &, #^2 &, #^3 &};

Then
Inner[Construct, funcs, #, List] & /@ myList


{{"aa", 1, 1030.3}, {"bb", 4, 8242.41}, {"cc", 9, 27818.1}, {"dd", 16, 65939.3}}


Hope this helps.

There is also
 MapThread[{#1 <> #1, #2^2, #3^3} &, Transpose@myList]

(* {{aa,1,1030.3},{bb,4,8242.41},{cc,9,27818.1},{dd,16,65939.3}} *)

or
Query[All, {1 -> (#1 <> #1 &), 2 -> (#^2 &), 3 -> (#^3 &)}]@myList

(* {{aa,1,1030.3},{bb,4,8242.41},{cc,9,27818.1},{dd,16,65939.3}} *)

